# Android XML id best practice

Tags: android, xml

Suppose I have an Activity, for which I set the content view from a XML file.

Let's say I have a button, acceptButton, in the Java code.

```
acceptButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptBtn);
```

In the above code, the Java name and the XML id are different. Is there a "best practice" or standard for naming widgets? For example, should the XML id be called acceptButton too, instead of acceptBtn? It seems trivial, but it annoys me what other people do, when they give the Android name and XML id completely different names.

Comment: They don't have to be the same. But they should be relative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no recommendation from Google about naming resources in xml files. Also checking [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) you find no mention about it, so the best would be taking a look in the SDK where you can see Google is not consistent in identifier naming.

Across the SDK you can find conventions as follow:

```
mHeaderText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerText);

mHeaderText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_text);

mHeaderText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HeaderText);
```

What I recommend is to be consistent per project. Decide for one naming convention and use it across the entire project.

Comment: Why they start their variables with small `m`? Why not `headerText`?

Comment: See `http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions`. Prefix `m` means the variable is a member field.

Comment: Thanks. This was bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

It is never mandatory that Java name and XML id should be same. And I don't think that there are any such naming standards provided by Google. But it is seems very good practice if both of them are same. By keeping them same, we can easily identify the control by name only when there are more than one controls.

Other way is you can define a naming style of java name and XML id and follow same for all the controls. But it is developer or project specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is never mandatory as Nirav said but having same name for id and Variable is good practice i always do this. This thing saves your time you don't need to remember different name for Id in xml and variable in code and also you just copy and paste after defining it in xml to code.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret it more colsely to Java conventions: "*AcceptBtn*" to point a class, "***acceptBtn***" to point an instance, "*accept_btn*" - others. **"id" is more like an instance**, definetely not a class. At least others. But I would prefer it as an instance.

```
R.id.AcceptBtn // As a class.
R.id.acceptBtn // As an instance.
R.id.accept_btn // Other cases.
```

Also as per Steve McConnel's "Code Complete" *acceptBtn* is more preferable **to be written as *acceptButton***. It is more readable and less writable, but we read code more often than write it. So readable code saves more time.